# How to add a binding to a xaml binding within a behavior?

Tags: wpf, behavior, multibinding

I have a behavior with a xaml interface of:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <b:ChartCanvasItemBehavior
               Source="{Binding MovieUri}"                                    
              Timeline="{Binding Path=Timeline, ElementName=ChartCanvasRightPanel, Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
                                                             
       />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The behavior creates an adorner that does:

```
public double Timeline
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(TimelineProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TimelineProperty, value); }
        }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Timeline.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimelineProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Timeline", typeof(double), typeof(MovieControlForChartCanvas), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));
```

To link the two in the behavior, I have:

```
var bindingMovieTime = new Binding
            {
                Source = mc,                                         
                Path = new PropertyPath(MovieControlForChartCanvas.TimelineProperty) 
            };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, iTimelineProperty, bindingMovieTime);


#region [Dependency Properties used to bind to the MovieControlForChartCanvas]
        // These dependecy properties have to be DIFFERENT then the dependency properties used for the ChartCanvasItemBehavior xaml interface. 
        // Using the same dependecy property for both bindings to the MovieControl and the Xaml interface results in losing one of the first bindings (i.e., the xaml binding).
        public double iTimeline
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(iTimelineProperty); }
            set { SetValue(iTimelineProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for iTimeline.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty iTimelineProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("iTimeline", typeof(double), typeof(ChartCanvasItemBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(0.0,
                (s, e) =>
                {
                    ChartCanvasItemBehavior d = s as ChartCanvasItemBehavior;
                    d.Timeline = (double)e.NewValue;
                }
                ));



        #endregion


        public double Timeline
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(TimelineProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TimelineProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Timeline.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TimelineProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Timeline", typeof(double), typeof(ChartCanvasItemBehavior  ), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
```

This seems to require a second property between the behavior and the adorner. If I use one property for both the behavior interface and the behavior-to-adorner interface, the first assignment to that behavior, i.e, from the xaml, gets overwritten by the binding to the adorner.

Can  this be done using only one dependency property in the behavior with multibinding?
If so, how?

To rephrase, is it possible to use one dependency property in the behavior to serve as an interface in both the xaml and to the adorner? (multibinding?)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can't the behaviour that creates the adorner simply set one of its properties to `this.Timeline`?

Comment: @mm8 Yes and no. The Timeline is being constantly updated by the running MediaElement contained within the adorner. So I am assuming that a binding between the adorner's Timeline and the behavior is needed.  When the binding between the Timeline property used to bind in the xaml is bound to the adorner, the xaml's binding is lost. Hence my use of a dedicated property to the adorner, iTimeline, which can then do a "this.Timeline" set and transfer via the xaml. i.e., the xaml is bound to Timeline and the adorner is bound to iTimeline with a "this.Timeline" used to transfer the data internally.

Comment: @mm8 Hence the question of if there is anyway to add a binding to the already existing binding of the xaml without losing the binding to the xaml and thereby use only one dependency property instead of two. Thanks.

Comment: You need some sort of synchronization between the two parties. Either use a binding or raise and handle events or something.